# (php) XML 2 TEXT is returning a 500 error

Tags: php, xml, text

I am writing a simple little script to read an xml file and print out the contents to a text file. But somewhere it keeps throwing me a 500 error and I cannot find it.

XML:

```
<calibredb>
  <record>
    <uuid>b32a07fd-dd70-4b00-acf4-395f2e69df72</uuid>
    <publisher>Boom! Studios</publisher>
    <title sort="Seven Warriors 2">Seven Warriors 2</title>
  </record>
</calibredb>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php

// Encryption Key
$key = "Ex6wCoVjh80Iu7ZAraanEEUyJmPHjCIt";


// Function To Generate A Unique ID
function asc2hex ($temp) {
    $data = "";
    $len = strlen($temp);
    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) $data.=sprintf("%02x",ord(substr($temp,$i,1)));
    return $data;
}

// Function To Generate A Unique ID
function encrypt($string, $key) {
    $result = '';
    for($i=1; $i<=strlen($string); $i++) {
        $char = substr($string, $i-1, 1);
        $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
        $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
        $result .= $char;
    }
    return asc2hex($result);
}

// Location For Text File
$file_text = fopen("comics.txt","w+");

// Initialize Reading Of XML File
$dom = new DOMdocument();
$dom->load('comics.xml');

foreach ($dom->getElementByTagName('record') as $entry) {

// Comic Publisher
$publisher = $entry->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent; 

// Comic Title
$title = $entry->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent;

// Comic ID
$id = $title.$publisher;
$id = encrypt($id, $key); 

// Text To Write
$text_to_write = $title." (".$publisher.") (".$id.")\r";

fwrite($file_text,$text_to_write);
echo $text_to_write." Added!<br/>";

}


fclose($file_text);

?>
```

Maybe a fresh set of eyes can point out where I went wrong!

Comment: What's in your server log?  Details of the error will be recorded there.

Comment: is XML in same directory and do you have write permissions there too. you dont check if fopen() was successful

Comment: A 500 error should not have anything to do with PHP, but rather represents a server configuration issue typically.

Comment: @MikeBrant 500 error means there's an internal problem executing the script.  It can be either a server problem or a code problem.

Comment: Put this in the beginning of your php script and run again - tell us what you see: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: The Error it returned was: • The website has a programming error. (not a response to Aleks G)

Comment: @AleksG Typically a PHP error (fatal error, etc.) in a script will return a 200 and an empty page in default apache/PHP configurations.

Comment: If you are running IIS, you have to configure your website to provide the full details in order to troubleshoot. By default, IIS is configured to only output the error details on the local machine, meaning you'd have to surf using the server's browser.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByTagName() in C:\Users\rackemup\Documents\My Web Sites\xml2text\index.php on line 45

Comment: lol im such a tard i found the error!

Comment: @MikeBrant That's not true.  My site is running on an almost default apache config and a fatal error in php produces 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($dom->getElementByTagName('record') as $entry) {
```

SHOULD BE:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('record') as $entry) {
```